# Generic LINQ TO SQL Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, generics

Lets say I have two L2S classes generated by the designer with one property as follows:

```
public class A
{
  public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
  public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}
```

I have a generic DataAccess class as follows:

```
public class DataAccessBase<T> where T : class 
    {
        NWDataContext dataContext = new NWDataContext();

        public IList<T> GetAllActive()
        {
            return dataContext.GetTable<T>()
                   .where(T.IsActive == true) -----> How can i do something like this?
                   .ToList<T>();
        }
   }
```

Now from the GetAllActive() how can I return all active objects of either A or B type. My guess is that I have to use reflection to do this but I am very new to reflection. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to pass to `Enumerable.Where` is a [`Predicate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx). A `Predicate<T>` is a delegate that can eat instances of `T` and return a bool; you can think of a predicate as representing a property that is either `true` or `false` about instaces of `T`.

Now, there is a larger issue which is that unless you put a constraint on `T`, the compiler has no way of knowing that `T` has a publicly readable property named `IsActive`. Thus, you have to define an interface (or a base class) that both `A` and `B` implement (or derive from) and tell the method `GetAllActive` that `T` implements (or derives from) this interface (or base class). You can do this by constraining `T` in the definition of `DataAccessBase`. Thus:

```
interface IIsActive {
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

class A : IIsActive {
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
class B : IIsActive {
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class DataAccessBase<T> where T : class, IIsActive {
    public IList<T> GetAllActive() {
    return dataContext.GetTable<T>()
                      .Where(x => x.IsActive)
                      .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assert that `T` implements an interface that defines `isActive`

```
public interface IIsActive
{
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class DataAccessBase<T> where T : IIsActive
```